# How to build a single jar with Vaadin 7 precompiled and add-on widgetsets?

Tags: vaadin7

I would like to build a single jar using Maven which contains all the precompiled Vaadin widgets + some add-ons so I can use this jar as a dependency to build components and  applications without having to re-declare dependencies.

All the pom.xml files I've seen are either for Vaadin 6 or assume that the widgetset is being built together with the application (war).

Does anyone have an example of pom.xml for Vaadin 7 which simply generates a jar with widgetsets?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at answer in similar question provided below. There is everything you need to know to set up building of separate jar with widgets with Vaadin 7.

[How can I compile only necessary widgets in Vaadin 7 with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21127433/1907924)