# Vaadin widgetset is in wrong location in jar (Embedded Jetty + Maven Assemble)

Tags: maven, jetty, vaadin, maven-assembly-plugin

I created a new Java project with the Maven Vaadin application archetype. My goal was to have an executable jar that deployed a Vaadin servlet on Jetty. I use the Maven assembly plugin.

When I assemble and run my application, I get the following error:

```
INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.sevag.MyAppWidgetset/com.sevag.MyAppWidgetset.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

When I execute "jar tf" on my jar, I noticed that the "com.sevag.MyAppWidgetset" files are located in /VAADIN/, not /VAADIN/widgetsets:

```
VAADIN/com.sevag.MyAppWidgetset/clear.cache.gif
...
VAADIN/com.sevag.MyAppWidgetset/com.sevag.MyAppWidgetset.nocache.js
...
```

How do I fix this?

I don't use a web.xml file, I rely on the Vaadin servlet annotations. This is the Vaadin servlet code (it's the default created by the Maven Vaadin archetype with the "Click me" button):

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@Widgetset("com.sevag.MyAppWidgetset")
public class MyUI extends UI {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {...}

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/myapp", "/myapp/*", "/VAADIN/*", "/vaadin/*" }, name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
}
```

My maven-assembly plugin is configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.sevag.myapp.MyApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The assembly.xml file looks like this:

```
...
<id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>target/classes</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

The Jetty servlet code is as follows:

```
server = new Server(PORT);

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setResourceBase("./src");

    context.setCopyWebDir(true);
    context.setCopyWebInf(true);

    ServletHolder vaadinLoader = new ServletHolder(new MyUI.MyUIServlet());

    context.addServlet(vaadinLoader, "/*");
    context.addServlet(vaadinLoader, "/VAADIN/*");
    context.addServlet(vaadinLoader, "/vaadin/*");
    context.addServlet(vaadinLoader, "/myapp/*");
    context.addServlet(vaadinLoader, "/myapp");

    server.setHandler(context);
```

**Edit**

I found a temporary (or possibly permanent) workaround. Since I don't need a custom widgetset, I followed this answer:

[How can I compile only necessary widgets in Vaadin 7 with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005268/how-can-i-compile-only-necessary-widgets-in-vaadin-7-with-maven/21127433#21127433)

The com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet is being put in the correct place in the jar (VAADIN/widgetset/com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet).